# Adding ALSA module in Python in Linux

Tags: software-installation, package-management, python, libraries

I have recently started working in linux, 
I wanted to to add ALSA module in my Python.
I have used this,

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

After that I've installed pyalsa package,

```
pyalsa installation,
wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/pyalsa/pyalsa-1.0.14rc3.tar.bz2

tar xf pyalsa-1.0.14rc3.tar.bz2

$ python setup.py build

# python setup.py install
```

but when I type help(alsaaudio) in the Python, it gives error that there is no such module

According to the alsaaudio, (http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/pyalsaaudio.html)

> Note: the wrappers link with the alsasound library (from the alsa-lib
>   package) and need the ALSA headers for compilation. Verify that you
>   have /usr/lib/libasound.so and /usr/include/alsa (or similar paths)
>   before building.

I do not understand what does that mean and what I am doing wrong in adding Alsa module in Python.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Read `INSTALL` again.

Comment: "I wanted to install ALSA inside my python". Sorry, I don't understand what this means. Can you clarify/elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't need to `python setup.py build` , When you download by hand a module you should do it, however  if you use install `pip` system  , you don't need to use the given command.

in debian-base systems you can see the following formula:

```
python-modulename #python2 
python3-modulename #python3
```

But if you didn't find in debian repository, you can download by or without dowunlowd just use:

```
pip install yourmoudle
pip3 install yourmodule
```

before pip system programmers used `easy_install`.

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. To answer the original question, you also have to install the Python headers: sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev

Answer (score 4):

python-pyalsa is available in Debian for wheezy/testing/unstable. You don't need to build/install from source.